# Laravel - EC2 Image Upload Folder Permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.6 app installed on an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance. Everything is working fine apart from image uploads. When I try and upload an image I get the following error message..

```
/var/app/current/storage/app/images/uploadedimage.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I have run the following command to set ownership and permissions are 755..

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/app/current/storage/app/images/
```

But I am still getting the error, can anyone shed any light on why this is happening and the correct permissions I should be setting?

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder? Try 755 for folders and 644 for files.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention permissions. They are 755, have updated question

Comment: What are the permissions for `/var/app/current/storage`? IIRC the entire storage dir needs to be 755.

Comment: Entire storage folder and all sub-directories are 755 and ec2-user:ec2-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this one in the end. The problem was ocurring because the apache service is running from a different user. I used this command to find out the user..

```
ps aux | egrep '([a|A]pache|[h|H]ttpd)' | awk '{ print $1}' | uniq | tail -1
```

Which returns a user of 'webapp' - So now I run my chmod code...

```
sudo chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app/current/storage/app/images/
```

And al now works correctly. Hope this helps somebody who has the same issue

Comment: Life save I got the simalr problem for getting permission for my WordPress installation on EC2 solved with `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content`